# i want to change Priority to 'High'

Tags: apex

```java
trigger TriggerTask on Task (after insert) {
    List<Task> Ts = new List<Task>();
    
    if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter) {
        for (Task newTask : Trigger.new) {
            Task updatedTask = new Task(
                Id = newTask.Id,
                Priority = 'High'
            );
            Ts.add(T);
        }
    }
    
   insert Ts;
}
```

```
// Debug code
Task t1= new Task();
insert t1;
System.debug('here is my new task'+t1.Id);
System.debug('here is my new task priority'+t1.Priority);
```

Comment: A title and a code dump generally aren't sufficient. We can't read your mind or log into your org, so you need to use words to tell us what the issue is. The more details you can include, the better. The issue(s) here are simple enough, so a moderately skilled contributor could determine what the issue is and how to address that. With even just a little more complex code though, that becomes hard to do. The easier you make it for others to understand your issue, the better the chance you'll get someone to help (and get _correct_ help).

Answer (score 1):

When you want to make changes to the record(s) that are going through a trigger, you should be using a `before` trigger (either "before insert" or "before update" in 99% of cases).

In such a trigger, you can change the data without the need for DML by making changes to the instance of the record(s) stored in `trigger.new` (insert or update trigger) or `trigger.newMap` (update trigger).

So...

- Change your trigger to be `before insert`
- Remove the `new Task()` bits, as well as the list, adding to the list, and the DML
- All you really need here is the loop with `newTask.Priority = 'High';` (yes, that's literally all you need)

Also, changes made during a trigger won't magically appear in `t1` in your second snippet. You need to query the record (and all the fields you want to access) *after the DML line* to get the updated data.

Comment: And as a supplement: You can't do an `insert` on a record that already has an Id. Even if we could, your code (as written) would go into an infinite loop (you'd be re-inserting the record that you're inserting, which would cause it to go through the trigger again and be inserted again). Using an `update` instead would be more appropriate, though you could also run into an infinite loop there too (and a `before` trigger is the correct approach here anyway, not DML).

Comment: And finally, this is something that could (should?) be taken care of through a flow (record-triggered, "optimize for fast field updates") rather than a trigger. If you're not just trying to practice writing triggers, you should definitely be using a flow instead. Also, keep in mind the saying **If everything is high priority, then nothing is high priority**.

Comment: My goal is to set the priority of new tasks to 'High' before they are inserted into the database. However, when I debug the trigger, it shows the priority as null (DEBUG|here is my new task prioritynull).

Comment: @Zedmed As I said in the final 2 sentences of my answer, you need to query the record to get updated data.