# System.DmlException:

Tags: apex, before-trigger

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, TaskTrigger1: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.SObjectException: DML statement cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old Trigger

this my code and i'm a beginner in salesforce

```java
trigger TaskTrigger1 on Task (before insert) {
    List<Task> newTasks = new List<Task>();
    
    if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore) {
        for (Task newTask : Trigger.New) {
            System.debug('Task is Found: ' + newTask);
            newTask.Priority = 'High';
            newTasks.add(newTask);
        }
        
        insert newTasks;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the same as https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/419819/i-want-to-change-priority-to-high/419820 and the solution/advice I provided in that question still applies. Get rid of the DML and the list, it's not needed.